# PHP AJAX within a table

Tags: php, ajax

I have a table that lists my students.. and the License Number Column will either shown the license number or if there is no number in the DB it will show a textbox..

Upon submit (note: no submit button, to keep it need i just press return) 
The results from the PHP script will be shown via Ajax.

My complete code is here. 
http://pastebin.com/9k0EKXA9

Here is the code within the license number cell on each row:

```
   <td><?php // check if license number exists. 
                    if($row['license_no'] == '')
                    {
                        //show form. 
                        ?>
                        <form method="POST" id="license_no_update"">
                            <input type="text" name="license_no" value="License Number" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" name="student_id"  />

                        </form>
                        <div id="output"></div>
                        <?php

                    }else{
                        //show license no. 
                        echo $row['license_no'];
                    }
                    ?></td>
```

Here Is the JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#license_no_update").submit(function() {

        var license_no_update = $(this).serialize();

        $.post('license_update.php', license_no_update, function(data) {

                // We not pop the output inside the #output DIV.
                $("#output").html(data);

        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

The problem i am having, even after searching google many times.. 
I know i have to have a new form & element id for each row of the table. 
but even when i do have those, i do not know how to get JQUERY to find that unique number..

currently with the code attached if i submit on the first row of the table, the correct results are displayed, if i submit on any other row nothing is displayed..

I hope that all makes sense.

Regards

Aaron

Comment: Are you recreating that form for each row? If so, you will need to give each a unique id. As it is now, it looks like each form will have the same id which is not valid.

Comment: Hi somesillyname, thats for the reply i have tried both ways, the problem is, if i have a unique ID i dont know how to get that id each time...... Evan's answer below makes sense by now i am unsure how to use the out put from each row ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.find()` to find the value of the hidden input within the clicked `form`. Notice the use of `$(this)` which is the form itself, and then you can narrow down the input by it's name, since you know the name.

However, it is unclear what you want to do with the `id` so I left that up to you.

```
 $("#license_no_update").submit(function() {

    var studentID = $(this).find("input[name='student_id']").val();

        var license_no_update = $(this).serialize();

        $.post('license_update.php', license_no_update, function(data) {

                // We not pop the output inside the #output DIV.
                $("#output-" + studentID).html(data);

        });

    return false;
});
```

**Update:**

Here is one way of creating unique `ID`'s for each `output`:

```
if($row['license_no'] == '')
                    {
                        //show form. 
                        ?>
                        <form method="POST" id="license_no_update"">
                            <input type="text" name="license_no" value="License Number" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" name="student_id"  />

                        </form>
                        <div id="output-<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>"></div>
                        <?php

                    }else{
                        //show license no. 
                        echo $row['license_no'];
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks Evan, as there are multuple  <div id="output"></div> how do i find the correct one to display the result in? cheers

Comment: @AaronBannister That is an issue - you don't ever want multiple elements sharing the same ID. So, when you loop through your code, keep some kind of an increment and append this incremental value to your ID. So instead of output, the `id` may be `output-1` and the next `id` may be `output-2`, etc.

Comment: i tried to use the student_id e.g. <div id="output<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>"></div>

But got confused when it come to calling it from JQUER, i had seen something like that posted somehwere earlier, $("#output"+studentID).html(data);

Comment: @AaronBannister Do you want me to write up a small example?

Comment: I would be very greatful if you could ! 8-)

Comment: @AaronBannister see the update, and also see the top section since the `output.html()` has changed.

Comment: Thanks, i am obviously doing something wrong.. here is hte page ww.fsma.co.uk/fsma/admin/view_students2.php  if you input into the first license number box and hit return, eveything works as it should, and any other box and nothing happens..

Comment: @AaronBannister Another issue I see is that all of your forms have the same ID - that is not valid. Perhaps give them a class name instead and trigger the jQuery call like `$(".form_class_here").submit(`

Comment: @AaronBannister I found your issue. It's in your PHP code. You're going to want to use the `student_id` as your logic (Instead of checking if the license number is empty). Instead, check if `student_id == $row[student_id']`

Comment: ur a genius!!!! Thanks for all your help.. I didnt change the last bit you mentioned as thats the bit that i need to use... but after changing the form name to a class it works perfectly!!! Thank you very much for you time, patience and guidance !!!